# Alternative syntax to access javascript function arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments

```
(function(arguments = {})
{
    console.log(arguments)
}
)("a","b","c")
```

prints

```
$ node args.js 
a
$ node --version
v8.9.4
```

Is there a way to access the actual arguments in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise against overriding the built-in `arguments` variable within a `function` definition.

You could spread the expected arguments instead using `...vargs`.

```js
(function(...vargs) {
  console.log(arguments); // Built-in arguments
  console.log(vargs);     // Variable (spread) arguments
})("a", "b", "c");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Please take a look at [the `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) over at MDN for more info.

The documentation notes that if you are using ES6 syntax, you will have to spread the arguments, because the `arguments` do not exist inside of an arrow (lambda or anonymous) function.

```js
((...vargs) => {
  try {
    console.log(arguments); // Not accessible
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);         // Expected to fail...
  }
  console.log(vargs);       // Variable (spread) arguments
})("a", "b", "c");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function f1() { console.log(Array.from(arguments)) }
f1(1, 2, 3)

function f2(...args) { console.log(args) }
f2(4, 5, 6)
```